# path with js / php files and ajax functions

Tags: php, javascript, path

I've got problems after I moved my files in a structered directory list (I used relative links in all files).

A quick overview:

```
www
  js
    functions.js
  php
    ajax.send.php       include ('./functions.php');
    ajax.delete.php     include ('./functions.php');
    functions.php
  other dirs that have no influence
  index.php             include ('./php/functions.php'); and ofc js embedding <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/functions.js"></script>
```

The ajax stuff on the startpage works, but the php functions within ajax.send.php and ajax.delete.php aren't working correctly (but the path is correct?!)
I've tried every possible path in theses two files but there's no way to get this stuff to work.

Have I missed something? I'm at the end of my rope.

Greetings Fabio

Comment: set a constant at the top of your stack __PATH_TO_PHP

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
ajax.send.php       include ('./php/functions.php');
ajax.delete.php     include ('./php/functions.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use absolute path. Try to use this construction:

```
ajax.send.php       include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';
index.php           include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';
```

Comment: There's no error, it's just not working. function_exists works, replaced my oop mysql connection in the function with some structured code to exclude an error in my class - doesn't work either. I have no clue ...

Comment: Try to use "require" instead of "include". And if there any problems with file inclusion it will trigger Fatal Error otherwise something wrong with your code.